# Modifying Dijkstra's algorithm to print the nodes in the shortest path

Tags: c++, graph

I'm wondering how I can modify this function to save the final shortest path of nodes. This is from my textbook with minor modificatons.

```
template <class vType, int size>
void weightedGraphType<vType, size>::shortestPath(vType vertex) {
int i, j;
double minWeight;

for (j = 0; j < gSize; j++) {
    smallestWeight[j] = weights[vertex][j];
}

bool weightFound[size];

for (j = 0; j < gSize; j++) {
    weightFound[j] = false;
}

for (i = 0; i < gSize; i++) {
    int v;
    cout << vertex << " to " << i << endl;
    minWeight = INFINITY;

    for (j = 0; j < gSize; j++) {
        if (!weightFound[j]) {
            if (smallestWeight[j] < minWeight) {
                v = j;
                minWeight = smallestWeight[v];
            }
        }
    }

    weightFound[v] = true;

    for (j = 0; j < gSize; j++) {
        if (!weightFound[j]) {
            if (minWeight + weights[v][j] < smallestWeight[j]) {
                smallestWeight[j] = minWeight + weights[v][j];
            }
        }
    }
} //end for
} //end shortestPath
```

Comment: Keep track of the nodes comprising the shortest-path, and print that at the end.  Are you having trouble with a specific part of that?

Comment: The first for loop inside the main loop finds the second node with the lowest weight. The next loop finds a path from that second node to the target node. If I simply save the value every time the smallest weight gets set with a new value, it has extra values in there for the paths that are not the shortest. My question is, how do I save a list of nodes that are in the shortest path, ignoring the other paths? If this was a recursive algorithm it would be clearer.

Comment: Here's a big hint: start at the end of your path and work backwards.

Comment: So putting the homework tag specifies that I'm looking for hints, not answers on stack overflow?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a hint: for each node, you know the smallest weight you have found to reach it. You also could know where that "shortest path to reach this node" came from right before you hit this node.

Comment: I need more of an explanation than that to understand what I need to do here.

Comment: an extra 'I came from' field in the graph, that you fill in when you have found the shortest path to a node

Answer (score 0):

Create array to remember the predecessor of destination node and then track back.

Here is the full implementation of modified dijkstra

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<set>
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<list>
#include<limits.h>
using namespace std;
    struct myHeapcmp{
     bool operator()(const pair<int,int> &a,const pair<int,int>&b){
      return a.second<b.second;
     }

    };

typedef list<pair<int,int> > AdjList;
typedef vector<AdjList> Graph;
typedef multiset<pair<int,int>,myHeapcmp>MinHeap;
vector<int> dijkstra(Graph g,int N,int s){
    vector<int>d(N,100);
    vector<int>  predecessor(N);
    d[s] =0;
    vector<int>p(N,-1);
    vector<MinHeap::iterator>HeapPos(N);
    MinHeap h;
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
     HeapPos[i] = h.insert(make_pair(i,d[i]));
     MinHeap::iterator it;
    while(h.size()>0){
     it = h.begin();
     int v = it->first;

     h.erase(it);
     AdjList::iterator it2;
     for(it2=g[v].begin();it2!=g[v].end();it2++){
       int u = it2->first;
       int w_uv= it2->second;
       if(d[u]>w_uv+d[v]){
         d[u]= w_uv+d[v];
         predecessor[u] = v;
         p[u]=v; h.erase(HeapPos[u]);
         HeapPos[u]= h.insert(make_pair(u,d[u]));
       }

     }
    }
    for(int i = 0;i<N;i++){
        int node = i;
        int pre = predecessor[i];
        cout<<i<<" :";
        while(pre!=s){
            cout<<pre<<" ";
            node = pre;
            pre = predecessor[node];
        }
        cout<<s<<endl;
    }

 return d;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

one way to do this would be to introduce one extra loop that iterates the algorithm over all the nodes, and with distance array you can store the "via node" element.
once you have shortest path calculated from each node to every other node, all you have to do is to follow the "via node" value that you have stored.
btw, in terms of efficiency, this algorithm sucks, it's O(n^3).